# Power BI - Substract rows based on a id

Tags: powerbi, dax, subtraction

I have two tables as follows:

| id | N1 | N2 | N3 | N4 | N5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | UP | REIT |  |  |  |
| 2 | UP | REIT | UPDigital | DI |  |
| 3 | UP | REIT | UPDigital | DI | SI |
| 4 | UP | REIT | UPdigital | DI | IT |
| 5 | UP | FCUP |  |  |  |

| id_entity | id_person | exit | join |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 10 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 10 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 25 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 12 | 0 | 1 |

I need to calculate people's joins and exits, so to calculate the exists I created the following measure

```
N exits = IF(CALCULATE(sum(Folha2[exit])-sum(Folha2[join])) < 0,0, sum(Folha2[exit])-sum(Folha2[join]))
```

And for the joins this

```
N joins = IF(CALCULATE(sum(Folha2[join])-sum(Folha2[exit])) < 0,0, sum(Folha2[join])-sum(Folha2[exit]))
```

This is the result, but it is not correct.

[image]

My problem is that this way it is not based on the id_person

For example, in the last two rows of the second table, the person with id_person=25 left entity 4 and the person with id_person=12 entered entity 4.
This way he subtracts the two lines not taking into account that they are two different people
The correct thing would be the following number of exists

```
UP - 1
FCUP - 0
REIT - 2
UPDigital -2
DI - 2
IT - 1
SI - 1
```

Is it possible to calculate this in Power bi ?

Comment: Can you please provide sample data and expected output [how to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow)

Comment: The data sample is the first two tables I put up
And the expected output is at the end of it all.

Comment: Please provide the sample data in a table format as mentioned in the link so that the person attempting to help you can easily attempt this. Please help the responder more to help you faster.

Comment: @smpa01o Ok. Done!